# Submitting a Form (Feedback) in PDF to a PHP File in Server

Tags: php, pdf, feedback

I am trying to implement a feedback system from a PDF file. I have set all the necessary fields and have added a button for submitting it in HTML format.

In the server I have a PHP script running which processes the QUERY tags sent from the PDF as Feed back. So far so good, but after submitting the PDF Form, the PDF is showing an error `No Input File Page Data    http://www.example.com/feedback.php` where `feedback.php` is the PHP script. The feedback data is submitted in the Server even though an error is showed in Client.

Also note that the PHP Script doesn't return any data.

Thanks

Comment: Returning a data fixed the problem in Adobe Acrobat 6.0, but its giving a different error in Adobe Reader 9.0, the error being `An error occurred during the submit process. Cannot  process content of type text/html`

Answer (score 1):

Acrobat will not handle returning data of type HTML.  Try setting the content type header for your response to application/vnd.fdf or you may have luck setting a 204 header (No Content) and sending that back instead.